# jquery IE8 selector bizarreness

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I'm working with an xml node of the following structure:

```
<CF>
    <T>
        <TX>title</TX>
        <em>15:2:</em>
    </T>
    <KW>
        <TX>SOMETHING ELSE</TX>
    </KW>
    <!-- OTHER TAGS, SOME OF WHICH HAVE A <TX> CHILD -->
</CF>
```

Things work more or less as I expect in firefox, but I'm getting weird behavior in IE8. For example, the following gives me a jquery object of length 14:

```
jQuery("T TX", xmlDoc).length
```

where it should be only one (the "CF" tag contains only one "T" tag, which in turn contains only one "TX" tag).

Adding to the strangeness, if I remove the "T" from the selector, as in the following:

```
jQuery("TX", xmlDoc).length
```

I get FEWER, rather than an equal or greater number of results (the jquery object's length is 12).

So, the first question is: if there's only one TX tag, and it has only one "T" tag, why does jquery find 14 "TX" tags which are descendants of a "T"?

The second question is: if I simplify the selector, removing the "T", why do I get fewer, rather than more results?

Am I doing something wrong, or have I stumbled upon a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```
jQuery('T', mydoc).find('TX').length
```

and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

There are 14 characters in "<TX>title</TX>". Since I don't know how many actual TX elements there are, I couldn't say if the 12 from the second query is the number of TX elements in the document.

Kind of crazy and off the wall...but perhapse the length property isn't returning what you think its returning?

Comment: Jrista, intersting theory (and impressive observation!) but "title" is just example text. In the real xml doc the text is longer.

Comment: lol...I had to try...it was the only non-obvious thing I could see. Any way you could post the full document? There might be more information that could be gleaned with more data...

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with parsing non-html tags in IE8 with jQuery. I just stumbled onto [this discussion](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/each-or-find-isn-t-working-in-ie8) where the proposed answer is to use Microsoft.XMLDOM to build your DOM object from the XML. Here is the key part:

```
xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async="false";
xmlDoc.loadXML(text);
```

I tried this and it fixed some problems I had been having with IE8 when building XML docs from strings ($() and $.find weren't returning anything, only $.filter would work).

Update: you might look at $.parseXML() instead.